# I want code in Perl for splitting a string with multiple delimiters

Tags: regex, perl

I have a string like this:

```
LOADID##49945-19-0-3540FAA-16995-16995%%ANAME##NWADVE15%%AID##51826%%AGNAME##ADDLEXPR%%AGID##49945%%HNAME##teranetcmoduat.teraner.com%%LOADDATE##07-12-16%%LOADTIME##02-04-53.end
```

I have to extract values for the parameters:

```
LOADID, ANAME, AID, AGNAME, AGID, HNAME, LOADDATE, LOADTIME
```

...and write it into text file.  Output format is:

```
49945-19-0-3540FAA-16995-16995|NWADVE15|51826|ADDLEXPR|49945|teranetcmoduat.teraner.com|07-12-16|02-04-53
```

Comment: Split your string by `%%`. Iterate over the results and then split by `##`.  Have a look at `perldoc -f split` http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html

Comment: You will also need `perldoc -f join` http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/join.html

Comment: As well as reading/writing files `perldoc perlopentut` http://perldoc.perl.org/perlopentut.html

Comment: Where did you get stuck with your regex?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a simple Perl script with 2 regex replacements will do
(tested with Perl 5)

```
$ cat input.txt
LOADID##49945-19-0-3540FAA-16995-16995%%ANAME##NWADVE15%%AID##51826%%AGNAME##ADDLEXPR%%AGID##49945%%HNAME##teranetcmoduat.teraner.com%%LOADDATE##07-12-16%%LOADTIME##02-04-53.end

$ echo 's/(.*?)##(.*?)(?:%%|\.end$|$)/$2|/g;s/\|$//' > pipeitup.pl

$ perl -p pipeitup.pl input.txt > result.txt

$ cat result.txt
49945-19-0-3540FAA-16995-16995|NWADVE15|51826|ADDLEXPR|49945|teranetcmoduat.teraner.com|07-12-16|02-04-53
```

The second regex replace `s/\|$//` is just added to remove the pipe at the end.
So if a final pipe doesn't bother you, then you can just golf it down to only the first regex replace `s/(.*?)##(.*?)(?:%%|\.end$|$)/$2|/g`.

And btw, just with a minor change you can print a header with the field names.
(since those names are in capture group 1 of the first regex)

```
$ head -n1 input.txt |perl -p -e 's/(.*?)##(.*?)(?:%%|\.end$|$)/$1|/g;s/\|$//' >header.txt
```

Comment: Thanks.... It works

Answer (score 2):

### Parsing

```
my %rec = split /##|%%/, $s, -1;
```

-or-

```
my %rec = map { split /##/, $_, 2 } split /%%/, $s;
```

The advantage of the latter one is that it supports keys with no values, as well as values that contain `##`. Simply put, it's more reliable.

### Printing

```
my @headers = qw( LOADID ANAME AID AGNAME AGID HNAME LOADDATE LOADTIME );

say join "|", @rec{@headers};
```

-or-

```
use Text::CSV_XS qw( );

my @headers = qw( LOADID ANAME AID AGNAME AGID HNAME LOADDATE LOADTIME );

my $csv = Text::CSV_XS->new({
   auto_diag => 2,
   binary    => 1,
   sep_char  => '|',
});

$csv->say(\*STDOUT, [ @rec{@headers} ]);
```

The later produces a pipe-separated CSV file, so it can support values that contain `|`, but it may employ CSV quoting.

Answer (score -1):

Based on your input, you could search for

```
^LOADID##([^%]+)%%ANAME##([^%]+)%%AID##([^%]+)%%AGNAME##([^%]+)%%AGID##([^%]+)%%HNAME##([^%]+)%%LOADDATE##([^%]+)%%LOADTIME##([^%]+).end$
```

and replace with

```
\1|\2|\3|\4|\5|\6|\7|\8
```

It:

- looks for the fixed parts, and captures the parameter values,
- assumes "no empty parameter values" (Could be addressed replacing `+` by `*` in the search expression as necessary.), and
- will fail, if any of the parameter values might include a percent sign.

See it in action: [RegEx101](https://regex101.com/r/tJ7nK1/1).

But string splitting might be more efficient.

Please comment if and as this requires adjustment / further detail.

Comment: I doubt the list of fields a rows has and their order are both guaranteed -- there would be no reason to include the field names in each row if that were the case -- but this solutions assumes it's constant.